# opentok streaming error in Xcode 9.0: OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc, opentok

I am using **opentok** in my Hybrid ionic app for live streaming.
I am facing issue that I am unable to see live streaming in **ios** app, although its working on my android app which is already published on Google Play, 
Now I need to publish my ios app but I am stuck with these errors showing in Xcode

```
"ERROR: OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError OT_MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: Argument 1 ('mediaStream') to webkitAudioContext.createMediaStreamSource must be an instance of MediaStream"

"ERROR: OT.exception :: title: Unable to Publish (1500) msg: GetUserMedia"
```

Device I am using is iPhone 6 (OS 11.0, Safari 11.0)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
For me, problem was in publisher options for OT.initPublisher.
Option "resolution" was redundant. It crashed everythin for ios only, I commented it -ant everything is ok now. Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure you using **OS 11.0& Safari 11.0**
I am using it like this

`publisher = OT.initPublisher('myPublisher', pubOptions, function(error) {
  if (error) {
     console.log("error");
    } else {
      console.log("Publisher initialized.");
    }
  });`

Comment: Yes, iphone 6+, safari 11.

Wrong param 'resolution' was in pubOptions

Comment: my pubOptions are var `pubOptions = {publishAudio:true, publishVideo:true};`

Comment: Did you try this - https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/web/basic-video-chat/? Is this works for you? If yes, you can step-by-step transfer right code to your project. That's how i find my problem =)

Comment: Update. I have read today, that camera is unavailable on iphone simulator on xcode. may be it's the reason for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cordova OpenTok Plugin to add live video to your Ionic applications:
https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/

The plugin allows you to publish, subscribe, and use the OpenTok Signaling API on both iOS and Android. For Ionic samples, take a look at the following repo: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ionic-samples